# NoMethodError in Car#index

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Showing app/views/car/index.html where line #3 raised:

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: `<h2>Current List of Cars</h2>`

2: `<dl>`

3: `<% @cars.each do |car| %>`

4: `<dt><%= car.name %></dt>`

5:  `<dd>`

6: `<%= car.description %><br />`

car_controller.rb:

```
class CarController < ApplicationController
  def add
      @title = "Add a New Car"

    if request.post?
      @car = Car.new(params[:car])
      @car.user_id = User.logged_in(session).id
    if @car.save
        flash[:notice] = "Car #{@car.name} added!"
        redirect_to :controller => :car, :action => :index
      end
    end
    @cars = Car.find(:all)
  end

  def edit
  end

end
```

what is the problem I dont understand

New error is

SyntaxError in Car#index

Showing app/views/car/index.html.erb where line #20 raised:

compile error
C:/Users/Jatinder/BitNami RubyStack projects/mercedes_mod 2/app/views/car/index.html.erb:20: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting kEND
C:/Users/Jatinder/BitNami RubyStack projects/mercedes_mod 2/app/views/car/index.html.erb:22: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
Extracted source (around line #20):

```
17: </dl>
18: 
19: <p><%= link_to "Add a Car", :controller => :car, :action => :add %></p>
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/car/index.html.erb

/views/car/index.html.erb

```
<h2>Current List of Cars</h2>
<dl>
<% @cars.each do |car| %>
  <dt><% @user.cars.each do |cars| unless @user.blank? %></dt>
  <dd>
    <%= car.description %><br />
    <%= link_to "Edit", 
          :controller => :car, 
          :action => :edit,
          :id => car.id %> |
    <%= link_to "Delete", 
          :controller => :car, 
          :action => :delete,
          :id => car.id %>
  </dd>
<% end %>
</dl>

<p><%= link_to "Add a Car", :controller => :car, :action => :add %></p>
```

New error yet again this time when I go back to add car page:

```
NoMethodError in Car#add

Showing app/views/car/add.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `errors' for #<Array:0x57841b0>
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <h1>Add a New Car</h1>
2: <%= error_messages_for :car %>
3: <% form_for :car do |f| %>
4:   <p>
5:     <%= f.label :name %>:
```

Comment: Can you provide more code, please? Where do you assign @cars?

Comment: @cars is assigned in the car.controller.rb

Comment: class CarController < ApplicationController
  def add
   @title = "Add a New Car"
 
    if request.post?
      @car = Car.new(params[:car])
      @car.user_id = User.logged_in(session).id
    if @car.save
        flash[:notice] = "Car #{@car.name} added!"
        redirect_to :controller => :car, :action => :index
      end
    end
    @cars = Car.find(:all)
  end

  def edit
  end

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `@cars` assignment in an `index` action.

```
def index
  @cars = @user ? @user.cars : Car.all
end
```

Comment: ok I did that now I get this erro
SyntaxError in Car#index
Showing app/views/car/index.html.erb where line #20 raised:

compile error
C:/Users/Jatinder/BitNami RubyStack projects/mercedes_mod 2/app/views/car/index.html.erb:20: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting kEND
C:/Users/Jatinder/BitNami RubyStack projects/mercedes_mod 2/app/views/car/index.html.erb:22: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
Extracted source (around line #20):

17: </dl>
18: 
19: <p><%= link_to "Add a Car", :controller => :car, :action => :add %></p>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/car/index.html.erb

Comment: I will add the index.html.erb file contents for viewing

Comment: Okay. The line `@user.cars.each do |cars| unless @user.blank?` is bad syntax. You can't put the condition there for one thing, and it isn't going to somehow replace the other loop. I updated my example code to show how you can set the `@cars` variable based on whether there is a user or not.

Comment: ok now I have made changes and that index page is working with a list of all added cars which currently is a big ass list of 'test' lol. But now when I go back to the add page I get a new error ?!! please view the following: 

NoMethodError in Car#add

Showing app/views/car/add.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `errors' for #<Array:0x57841b0>
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <h1>Add a New Car</h1>
2: <%= error_messages_for :car %>
3: <% form_for :car do |f| %>
4:   <p>
5:     <%= f.label :name %>:

Comment: OK now everything is working but the problem now is I have to delete this line of code "@car.user_id = User.logged_in(session).id" from my car_controller.rb to get the add car function to work and display the index page with the list of cars. But I wanted this function to show the user id of who posted it.

Comment: That's because `error_messages_for :car` is looking for `#errors` on `@car`. It's just a convenience method. If you want to use the same template for new and edit, define a `new` action on your controller that sets `@car = Car.new`.

Comment: everything is working now so far thanks for help just like i said I can not show the user id to show who posted what, but im sure that is because I am missing something