# NoMethodError in Pins#index, undefined method `stringify_keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am not sure why I am receiving this error. There must be an error, but unfortunately I cannot find it at the moment.

Index.html.erb:

```
<div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
    <div class="box panel panel-default">
      <%= link_to image_tag(pin.image.url(:medium)), pin %>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p><%= pin.description %></p>
        <p><strong><%= pin.user.email if pin.user %></strong><p>

        <% if pin.user == current_user %>
          <div class="actions">
          <%= link_to edit_pin_path(pin) do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            Edit
            <% end %>
            <%= link_to 'Delete', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            Delete
            <% end %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

in my console, error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<Pin:0x007f568d39a428>):
    12:             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
    13:             Edit
    14:             <% end %>
    15:             <%= link_to 'Delete', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
    16:             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    17:             Delete
    18:             <% end %>
```

it seems if I edit `

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>`
```

to

```
<%= link_to pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
```

it works and the page loads, but creates other problems that I didn't have before such as not loading the 'delete' option on my 'pins' when a user is signed in. However, they show up when no one is signed in :/

Comment: Are you getting an error in your controller? Could you paste the full error that you're getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoMethodError in Car#index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034106/nomethoderror-in-carindex)

Comment: @Benjamins Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail, my error is 'undefined method `stringify_keys', I believe my problem to located in the code listed above, as that is where my error leads me.

Comment: Please post the full error message including the whole stack trace.

Comment: Created an edit for you to view. Hopefully the new information will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

When writing a link_to with a block afterwards it does not need the text content of the link.

```
<%= link_to pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
   Delete
<% end %>
```

In your code when passing in the `link_to 'delete', pin, ... do` it tries to parse the pin as part of the options hash

As for your delete buttons only showing up when someone isn't signed in, my best guess would be your `pin.user` is `nil` which matches when no one is signed in.  So maybe update that conditional to be `if current_user.present? && pin.user == current_user`